# cakephp jquery: alert box not popping up when link is clicked

Tags: jquery, cakephp, onclick, alert

I'm new to jquery. I'm trying to get an alert box to popup with the user clicks on a link. 
When i click on the link below, the alert message is not popping up.

```
echo $this->Html->link('My Name', '#',array('id'=>'#MyName'));
$this->Js->get('#MyName')->event('click',$this->Js->alert('whoa!'),array('wrap'=>false));
```

The following is from view source for the above code:

```
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {$("#MyName").bind("click", alert("whoa!"););});
//]]>
</script>
```

The following is the html generated in the browser from view source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 

Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   <title>
                Merry Parents   </title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" /><link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/cake.generic.css" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
       /* $(document).ready(function () {
                alert('JQuery is succesfully included');
        });*/
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
                <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
<div>
<div style="float:left; width:98%; background-color:#ffffff;">
<img src="/img/logo.png" alt="" /><div style="float:right; width:5%; top:100%; right:10%;">
<a href="/pages/home">Home</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/navbar.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="menu">
        <ul id="nav">
<!--        <li><a href="/pages/home">Home</a></li>
-->         <li><a href="#">Our Program</a><ul>
            <li><a href="/pages/preschool">Preschool</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/kindergarten">Kindergarten</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/summer_camp">Summer Camp</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a><ul>
            <li><a href="/pages/about_us">Merry Flowers</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/tour_our_school">Tour Our School</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pages/contact_us">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">My Child</a><ul>
            <li><a href="/merry_parents/register">Report Card</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Events</a><ul>
            <li><a href="#">News &amp; Events</a>               <ul>
                    <li><a href="/pages/sports_day">Sports Day</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pages/annual_day">Annual Day</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="/pages/list_of_holidays">List of Holidays</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a><ul>
            <li><a href="/pages/faq">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="/feedbacks/add">Feedback</a></li>
            <li><a href="/forum/home">Discussion</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Admissions</a><ul>
            <li><a href="/students/add">Enroll Now</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul><!--finish ul nav-->
        </div> <!--finish div menu-->
</body>
</html>     </div> <!-- finish div header -->
        <div id="content">
            <div>
            <div id="content1">

            <a href="#" id="#MyName">My Name</a>            </div>
            <div id="content2">
                <a href="/students/add"><img src="/img/admission_open.gif" alt="admissions" /></a><img src="/img/contact_us.gif" alt="" />              
            </div> 
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="footer"> 
        &copy;  2011 Merry Flowers Montessori | Designed by VRI Web
    </div>
</div><!--div container finish-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {$("#MyName").bind("click", alert("whoa!"););});
//]]>
</script></body>
</html>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this
```

Remove # before 'MyName' symbol
    echo $this->Html->link('My Name', '#',array('id'=>'MyName'));

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MyName").click(function (){     
    alert("whoa!");
    return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about cakephp, but the jQuery code generated is surely incorrect. If you intend to attach the click handler on an element with an id `MyName` the code should be as follows

```
$("#MyName").bind("click", function (event) {
   alert("whoa!");
   return false;
});
```

Read more about the ID selector [here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: i've changed the id to "#MyName" and it still doesn't work. No popup alert.

Comment: @vaanipala : Can you share the html generated?

Comment: yes i've updated my question with all the modifications and the latest html generated.

Comment: i know that jquery is working fine coz' when i put <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                alert('JQuery is succesfully included');
        });
    </script> in the layout file the alert message is popping up on all the pages.

Comment: Can you paste the generated html? By generated I mean html that is rendered in the broswer

Comment: Ok, i have pasted the html generated in browser (from view source).

Comment: @vaanipala : `<a href="#" id="#MyName">My Name</a>` should be `<a href="#" id="MyName">My Name</a>`. so i suppose your cakephp code should be `echo $this->Html->link('My Name', '#',array('id'=>'MyName'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Html->link('My Name', '#',array('id'=>'MyName'));
$this->Js->get('#MyName')->event('click',$this->Js->alert('whoa!'));
```

The above code pops the alert message.

```
 $this->Js->get('#MyName')->event('click',$this->Js->alert('whoa!'),array('wrap',false));
```

doesn't work, so, i ommitted array('wrap',false) which is used to prevent the alert message from being wrapped with an anonymous function.

The following is what i'm getting in browser source:

```
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {$("#MyName").bind("click", function (event) {alert("whoa!");
return false;});});
//]]>
```

Since wrap defaults to true you can see function (event) wrapping around the alert msg and return false.